# Exception while using activemq's BrokerViewMBean

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I am trying to access jmx functionality from the same process within which I am running the activemq broker and expose some properties through a web service. The code looks as follows:

```
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    try {
        ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=locahost,Type=Broker");
        BrokerViewMBean brokerViewMBean = JMX.newMBeanProxy(mbs, name, BrokerViewMBean.class);
        ObjectName[] queues = brokerViewMBean.getQueues();
        .
        .
        .
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run this code, I get the following exception:

> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException    at
>   $Proxy51.getQueues(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.myinc.MyObject.getAllQueues(MyObject.java:37)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:211)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:141)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=locahost,Type=Broker   at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1094)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:662)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:638)
>     at
>   javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:263)
>     ... 39 more

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong and what is this exception trying to say?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The clue is in the caused by part of the exception:

```
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=locahost,Type=Broker at
```

The object name you are using must be incorrect or the broker isn't running yet.  You can use jconsole to attach to the process and see what the valid ObjectNames are.

Comment: Its my bad. Even after looking into the object name many times, I didn't notice that I have misspelled localhost (locahost). Based on your comment I looked again very carefully and I noticed the mistake. Thanks for your help and time.